# Del list and next list element in list if string exist

Tags: python, arrays, list, del

I have an example:

```
list = [['2 a', 'nnn', 'xxxx','last'], ['next, next'], ['3', '4', 'next']]

for i in range(len(list)):
  if list[i][-1] == "last":
    del(list[i+1])
    del(list[i])
```

I'd like to delete this list where the last item is "last" and the next item on the list.
In this example there is a problem every time - I tried different configurations, replacing with numpy array - nothing helps.

Trackback:
`IndexError: list index out of range`

I want the final result of this list to be `['3', '4', 'next']`

Give me some tips or help how I can solve it.

Comment: When you [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite - what is the value of `i`? If you delete items from the list will the *original* `range(len(list))` still apply?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Instead of deleting the list, try creating a new list and copy elements from the old list. This will, of course, depend on your resource constraints.

Comment: @wwii I've also checked it and it works for ints

Comment: @PalashGoel I tried it too, but the only solution I had was `list2.append(list[i])` - with the condition `if list[i][-1] ! = "last"` - but I need to delete both `list[i]` and as well as `list[i+1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
l = [['2 a', 'nnn', 'xxxx','last'], ['next, next'], ['3', '4', 'next']]
delete_next = False
to_ret = []
for x in l:
    if x[-1] == 'last':
        delete_next = True
    elif delete_next:
        delete_next = False
    else:
        to_ret.append(x)
```

Using a variable to store if this needs to be deleted

Comment: yes, but in this case it breaks my previous list - if the list is, for example:`l = [['2 a', 'nnn', 'xxxx','last'], ['next, next'], ['3', '4', 'next'],["text","text"]]`
the effect of this code will be:
`['3', '4', 'next', 'wwa', 'wwaa']`
but I want the structure to be preserved:
`['3', '4', 'next'],["text","text"]`

Comment: No. The output will be as expected

Comment: `to_ret.append(x)` - this will work fine.
The `+ =` operator will add to one list.
Anyway, thank you, all you had to do was use bool and solve the problem - I don't know why I didn't think of it before.

Comment: Didn't know there was a difference b/w += and .append. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the list, if the last element of that iteration == 'last' then skip, else, append to a new list.

Also, it is not recommended to edit lists while iterating over them as strange things can happen, as mentioned in the comments above, like the indexes changing.

```
l = [['2 a', 'nnn', 'xxxx','last'], ['next, next'], ['3', '4', 'next']]
newlist = []
for i in l:
    if i[-1] == 'last':
        continue
    else:
        newlist.append(i)
```

Comment: would also rename your list to something else, like L, as list is an object type in python

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and  help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?